MediaRecorder not firing event
I've been trying to get the data from the media stream of a microphone when a user speaks into it.
My goal is to continually send that data over to a web server as until the user closes the mic by a button.
I've tried a lot like this from mdn unfortunately its in javascript and I try to rewrite it in typescript which I think is where my problem arises. At the moment this is what I have
  mediaRecorder?: MediaRecorder
  chunks: any = []
  dest?: MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode
  constraints = { audio:true, video: false }

  async record_audio() {
    if (navigator.mediaDevices){
      var $this = this;
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(this.constraints).then((stream)=>{
        this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
        this.mediaRecorder.start();
        //this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = this.pushChunks;

        this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
          console.log("pushing chunk")
          $this.chunks.push(e.data);
        };
        console.log('starting recorder...')
      })
     
    } else { alert('getUserMedia not supported.'); }
  }


The method is called but the mediaRecorder.ondataavailable is never called. I don't know if the method gets destroyed after it exits or something.
How do I continually get the data in this stream so I can upload it to a web server?
Addition
I worked around to write this methods. The AudioWorkletNode fires it process method continually but unfortunately again, the worklet has to be implemented in a different class and file which I cannot utilize the resources in the current class component
I chipped in the commented code into the block to see if it will fire but it doesn't
async record_audio() {
    console.log("audio is starting up ...");

    if (await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true, video: false})){
      this.start_microphone(await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true, video: false}))
    } else { alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.'); }
  };  
 
      

  async start_microphone(stream:MediaStream){

        // this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)
        // console.log('starting recorder...')
        // this.mediaRecorder.start();
        // this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = this.pushChunks;

        // this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (e) {
        //   console.log("pushing chunk")
        //   this.chunks.push(e.data);
        // };

    this.gainNode = this.audioCtx!.createGain();
    //gain_node.connect( $this.audioCtx!.destination );

    this.microphone_stream = this.audioCtx!.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    this.microphone_stream.connect(this.gainNode); 

    await this.audioCtx!.audioWorklet.addModule("/assets/audio-processor.js");
    this.processorNode = new AudioWorkletNode(this.audioCtx!, "audio-processor");
    this.microphone_stream.connect(this.processorNode);
  }


try moving mediaRecorder.start() to after you set the ondataavailable event handler

@ITgoldman I just did that but still nothing logged in the console of the event

why is record_audio an async method? not the issue, just odd coding

Where is this invoked? is it in ngAfterViewInit? have you tried pushing it further in the event queue by wrapping it with setTimeout() at the same time?

@JaromandaX I have async there because we are calling a method that returns a result from a promise and if you can't await in a non async method

@AlexPappas its invoked on the click of a button

you're not using await, you're using .then

@JaromandaX oh I see what you're referring to now. I changed implementation to the one below though

You can try this approach to resolve the issue:
start function
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: false })
  .then(stream => {
    if (!this.audioContext) {
      this.audioContext = new AudioContext();
      this.gainNode = this.audioContext.createGain();
    }
    const source = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    source.connect(this.gainNode); 
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    this.mediaRecorder.start(1000);

    this.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e: BlobEvent) => {
      this.chunks.push(e.data);
    };
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error accessing microphone:', error);
  });

where
audioContext = new AudioContext();
gainNode = audioContext.createGain();


Picking from this answer, I saw that `mediaRecorder.start(1000) has a time duration which I was leaving out. When a time in milliseconds is specified tells the number seconds to record before emitting the ondataavailable event. So a smaller number makes it faster or more times the event will be emitted. So I would mark this as correct

I actually have missed this key part of the code snippet above. I will try to investigate further and find an explanation for how it works out with ondataavailable.
